# Http Status must not be null error how to solve that error

Tags: https, http-status-codes, notnull

{"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.946","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.controllers.subscription.SubscriptionServiceController","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6","level":"INFO","transactionid":"22434353edghf32","message":{"responseObject":{"**httpStatus":null**,"status":null,"description":null,"subscriptionId":null,"subscriptionProviderId":null,"subscriptionPaymentSource":null,"customerId":"27780347403","subscriptionType":null,"subscription":{"subscriptionId":"790","subscriptionProviderId":"SOA","subscriptionName":"8/1 Day 75MB (R8)/1 day","registrationChannel":"Facebook-MADAPI","sendSMSNotification":false,"autoRenew":false,"amountBefore":0.0,"amountAfter":0.0,"nonGSM":true,"cvmoffer":false,"links":[]},"error":null,"subscriptionName":null,"frequency":null,"subscriptionStatus":null,"subscriptionLength":null,"timestamp":null,"partnerName":null,"links":[],"statusCode":"6001","statusMessage":"Insufficient Funds","supportMessage":"Insufficient funds to complete migration","transactionId":null,"sequenceNo":null}}} {"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.946","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.controllers.subscription.SubscriptionServiceController","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6","level":"INFO","transactionid":"22434353edghf32","message":{"responseObject":{"subscriptionProviderId":"SOA","subscriptionName":"8/1 Day 75MB (R8)/1 day","registrationChannel":"Facebook-MADAPI","sendSMSNotification":false,"autoRenew":false,"amountBefore":0.0,"amountAfter":0.0,"nonGSM":true,"cvmoffer":false,"links":[],"statusCode":"6001","statusMessage":"Insufficient Funds","supportMessage":"Insufficient funds to complete migration"}}} {"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.947","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6","level":"INFO","transactionid":"22434353edghf32","message":"Exeption thrown :: IllegalArgumentException, Localized Message :: **HttpStatus must not be null Message :: HttpStatus must not be null"}** {"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.947","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6","level":"ERROR","transactionid":"22434353edghf32","message":"Exception catch in global exception handler."} {"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.948","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6","level":"INFO","transactionid":"22434353edghf32","message":{"responseObject":{"httpStatus":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","error":"Internal Server Error","description":"An internal server error occurred and processing could not be completed.","links":[]}}} {"@timestamp":"2023-10-25 10:15:45.948","@version":"1","logger":"za.co.mtn.aggregator.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-6",

Http status must not be null so its printing httpstatus = null  what should i do that particular fix.